# How does truncating a series affect "upstream" values in the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi, rounding-error, truncation-error

It is known that truncating the Gregory’s series to 5,000,000 terms leads to an "almost but not quite" value for π:

$$
\pi=4 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2 k-1}=4(1-1 / 3+1 / 5-1 / 7+\cdots)
$$

```
Gregory’s series : 3.14159245358979323846464338327950278419716939938730582097494182230781640...
π :                3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640...
```

Note the 7th decimal place is a `4` instead of the proper `6`.

But how does truncation affect a number so far upstream from the truncation? In other words, if we are capping the series at 5 million decimal places, why would the 7th decimal place be affected? Is it a rounding that "propagates" back up the number?

UPDATE

It turns out that small perturbations of the correct decimal expansion for π appear when truncating the formula. It's actually not too surprising in terms of the problem of induction, however why the perturbations appear so early in the expansion is still quite interesting. In this particular case, capping the series at 5,000,000 steps ends up being exactly one-half of a fairly large power of ten, which apparently explains the perturbation, although I can't say I quite understand why.

Comment: " capping the series at 5 million decimal places" What do you mean by that? That is not correct.

Comment: Only letting it run to 5 million places

Comment: We are keeping 5 million terms in the sum, but what does that have to do with decimal places? We need very many terms in the sum just to get a few decimal places of accuracy in your approximation to pi.

Comment: You don't get 5 million decimal places from 5 million terms of this series. It converges much more slowly than that. In fact, the 5 millionth term has absolute value $1/(10^7 - 1) \approx 10^{-7}$, so it's no surprise that the 7th decimal place is incorrect.

Comment: @littleO yes that’s correct. I see now.

Comment: @Bungo right. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @GEdgar yes that is extremely interesting, and it threw my thinking down an odd path, leading to my posted question which I now see is nonsensical.

Comment: @Bungo I believe it’s a mystery with no current answer. One of the enigmas baked into pi, that only experimental mathematics (done on computers) were able to discover by virtue of computation being able to run towards infinity. Something deep is happening here. Extremely fascinating.

Answer (score 3):

The surprising thing--which is known to happen in this series but rarely happens with other series--is: many correct digits appear after the first incorrect digit.  An interesting explanation is here:

*Borwein, J. M.; Borwein, P. B.; Dilcher, K.*, [**Pi, Euler numbers, and asymptotic expansions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2324715), Am. Math. Mon. 96, No. 8, 681-687 (1989). [ZBL0711.11009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0711.11009).

Comment: Any availability outside a paywall?

Comment: @Cybernetic Did you try the "read online (100 articles/month for free)" option under Alternative Access Options?

Comment: Ahh nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have just subtracted $\frac{4}{9,999,999}$ so your partial sum is too small by about half that

and are about to add $\frac{4}{10,000,001}$ which would make the partial sum too big by about half that

so your error is approximately $\frac{2}{10,000,000}=\frac{1}{5,000,000}$.

If you sum $n$ terms, the error is not exactly $\frac1n$; a better expression  is $$\pi\approx 4 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2 k-1} +(-1)^n\left(\frac1n- \frac{1}{4n^3}+ \frac{5}{16n^5}- \frac{61}{64n^7}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^9}\right)$$

and for example when $n=5$ the partial sum is wrong in the first decimal place, but with the adjustment the approximation is correct up to five decimal places.  The numerators in the adjustment are in [OEIS A000364](https://oeis.org/A000364) or signed in [A028296](https://oeis.org/A028296).

Coming to $n=50000000$, the powers of $5$ largely soak up the powers of $2$ in the denominator so the error terms become successively smaller and seem separate: $+0.0000002$ $ -0.000000000000000000002$ $ + 0.0000000000000000000000000000000001$ $ -0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000122$ $ +\cdots$ and so only a few of the decimal places are changed, as you noticed in your calculations

```
3.14159245358979323846464338327950278419716939938730582097494182230781640
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640
        ^             ^            ^            ^^^          ^^^ 
        2            -2            1           -122          277
```